# Initializing a struct's members

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I was reading about `struct`s in the C language and I do not fully understand the way a `struct` is initialized.
Please consider the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tnode {
    char *word;
    int count;
    struct tnode *left;
    struct tnode *right;
};


int main (void)
{
    struct tnode *root;
    struct tnode tn1;
    root = &tn1;
    printf("%d\n", root->count);

    if (root->word == NULL)
        printf("word is NULL\n");
    else
        printf("word is not NULL\n");

    if (root->right == NULL)
        printf("rightis NULL\n");
    else
        printf("right is not NULL\n");
}
```

Output:

```
0
word is NULL
right is not NULL
```

I can't understand why `root->right` is not initialized to `NULL`. Could someone please throw some light?

Comment: Try `static struct tnode *root;` and see the results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I can't understand why `root->right` is not initialized to `NULL`.

C does only initialise variables defined globally and/or declared `static` be itself. All other variables are left uninitialised if not done explicitly by the code.

The code you show reads uninitialised variables. Doing so might invoke undefined behaviour. Seeing `0` or `NULL` is just (bad) luck. The variables could hold anything.

From the [C11 Standard (draft) 6.7.9/10](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p10):

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;